# FOSUserBundle: no "Bad credentials" error when overriding the SecurityController (login):

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have just followed the instructions to override a controller in `FOSUserBundle` [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html).

In my case I want to override the login controller so I have created a new bundle called `UserBundle` and the `SecurityController` like this below (as you can check I have just copied the original `SecurityController` methods).

```
namespace UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
die("Here is entering when showing the login form and when submitting it");
        /** @var $session \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session */
        $session = $request->getSession();
        if (class_exists('\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security')) {
            $authErrorKey = Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR;
            $lastUsernameKey = Security::LAST_USERNAME;
        } else {
            // BC for SF < 2.6
            $authErrorKey = SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR;
            $lastUsernameKey = SecurityContextInterface::LAST_USERNAME;
        }
        // get the error if any (works with forward and redirect -- see below)
        if ($request->attributes->has($authErrorKey)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get($authErrorKey);
        } elseif (null !== $session && $session->has($authErrorKey)) {
            $error = $session->get($authErrorKey);
            $session->remove($authErrorKey);
        } else {
            $error = null;
        }
        if (!$error instanceof AuthenticationException) {
            $error = null; // The value does not come from the security component.
        }
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = (null === $session) ? '' : $session->get($lastUsernameKey);
        if ($this->has('security.csrf.token_manager')) {
            $csrfToken = $this->get('security.csrf.token_manager')->getToken('authenticate')->getValue();
        } else {
            // BC for SF < 2.4
            $csrfToken = $this->has('form.csrf_provider')
                ? $this->get('form.csrf_provider')->generateCsrfToken('authenticate')
                : null;
        }
        return $this->renderLogin(array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error,
            'csrf_token' => $csrfToken,
        ));
    }
    /**
     * Renders the login template with the given parameters. Overwrite this function in
     * an extended controller to provide additional data for the login template.
     *
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    protected function renderLogin(array $data)
    {
        return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig', $data);
    }
    public function checkAction()
    {
        throw new \RuntimeException('You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration.');
    }
    public function logoutAction()
    {
        throw new \RuntimeException('You must activate the logout in your security firewall configuration.');
    }
}
```

UserBundle.php

```
namespace UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class UserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

The problem: after submittting the login form shown at `/login`, I don't get the error `Bad credentials` when they the credentials are bad.

Here is my `security.yml` file:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
                # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Note: debugging inside `loginAction` at the line where the comment `// last username entered by the user` is, the value of `$error` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

My fault: I was using a template which was not showing the errors.